# Android Eclipse ADT 8.0.0 (and 8.0.1) problem - can't create views hierarchy with drag and drop in the Outline view

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, outline-view

Before the newest version I was able to create hierarchies using drag
n' drop, performed on the outline view.
Since the upgrade, I can't and the controls ('+', '-' and arrows) are
missing.

So how am I suppose to build view hierarchies now?

Answer (score 1):

Drag the `View` to on of the edges you want to have that `View` on if you are using a `RelativeLayout`. That should work.

If you are using a `LinearLayout` you can just drag'n drop them as you are used to.

Comment: In the relative layout you're right. but in the linear layout - I dragging and dropping just won't put a TextView inside a LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

Apperantly that's a known issue and will be fixed in ADT 9.0. you can install experimental / nightly build of it now.

Answer (score 1):

drag'n drop of views in a linear layout works... provided the layout is not empty and its heigth/width are not set to wrap_content !!!

example : create a linearLayout. Set the layout width / height to fill parent or some fixed value (e.g. 64dip). You can now drag'n drop, let's say, a textView in it.